# Usage of WHERE CLAUSE in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to write SQL queries in Python.
I have a data frame **df** with columns **date, ID and amount**

Every month I am getting a new load of data. I have to calculate the average amount for a particular ID for the last 12 months (means we will have 12 records for that one ID).

Currently, my approach is

```
M1 = pd.date_range(first_day_of_month, last_day_of_12_month, freq='D').strftime("%Y%d%m").tolist()
df["new"] = df[(df['date'].isin(M1))]['amount'].mean()
```

Now I want to upload this average as a new column, each ID with current (latest) time stamp has average of last 12 months amount. Tried using groupby but was not able to apply properly.

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL?

Comment: Sorry, will reframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
mask = d.date.between(datetime.datetime(2019,1,1),datetime.datetime(2019,12,31))
d[].groupby(['ID'])['amount'].mean()
```

I guess ? maybe ?

Comment: I think the amount part is missing in this.